# Erro em troca de elementos na matriz

Tags: python, array, python-3.x, array-multidimensional

Estou tentando trocar dois elementos de posição nesta matriz.
Depois de algumas trocas os elementos começam a trocar entre si em um padrão aparentemente aleatório.
Alguém poderia me identificar o erro por favor?

```
def trocamatrizDess(matrizDes,seguradoX, seguradoY, xis, ips):

    auxRes = matrizDes[seguradoX][seguradoY]

    matrizDes[seguradoX][seguradoY] = matrizDes[xis][ips]

    matrizDes[xis][ips] = auxRes
```

```
#Matriz inicial:
     -97   -298  -198   1
     -200  -98   -297 -199
     -197  -100  -299 -300
     -99     3     2    0

#Matriz solução:
0 -100 -200 -300
1 -99 -199 -299
2 -98 -198 -298
3 -97 -197 -297
```

```
#Exemplo minimo completo e verificavel:



"""
A matrizResDesenho é uma matriz de inteiros que identificam sprites que formam uma imagem
embaralhada, o objetivo é formar a imagem original. Se um sprite deveria estar na
posição (3,0) para a imagem original estar correta o valor na matrizResDesenho[x][y] dele é
 calculado por -100*x + y, nesse caso seria -300 , tendo x e y como a posição atual dele.

A condiçãoPrimaria é True se o mouse estiver sobre um dos sprites dessa matriz e clicar 
nele. O x e y do momento identificam a posição do sprite, e assim segurando se torna True,
 pois é como se estivesse segurando o sprite.

Ao clicar em outro sprite já tendo um segurado, ambos elementos da matriz devem trocar de 
posição e agora segurando é false.

Os sprites também mudam de posição, mas isto não vem ao caso pois essa parte esta 
funcionando bem, só essa matriz de inteiros que da erro.

"""
         for x in range(4):
            for y in range(4):
                if (condicaoPrimaria):
                        if(not segurando):
                            cordX, cordY = x, y
                            segurando = True
                        else:
                            trocamatrizDess(matrizResDesenho, cordX, cordY, x, y)
                            segurando = False
```

Comment: Depende muito de como está fazendo a chamada dessa função e como está definindo as posições que serão trocadas. O comportamento que citou não parece ser causado por um erro nessa função.

Comment: Eu basicamente chamo ela dentro de dois loop for, um que itera a variável x e o outro a y. 
Se uma dada condição acontecer dentro desses loops armazena o x e o y deste momento nas variáveis seguradoX e seguradoY, se ela acontecer mais uma vez chama essa função passando o seguradoX e seguradoY, e o x e y atuais.

Comment: Exatamente esses dois laços que podem estar causando o problema. Elabore um [mcve] demonstrando o problema para facilitar nosso entendimento.

Comment: Publicação editada com o exemplo incluído. O que mais me intriga é que aparentemente esta correto em tudo que olho no código.

Comment: Para ser um [mcve] será necessário que você adicione a matriz que está utilizando e descreva qual seria o resultado esperado. Também é essencial explicar o que é `condicaoPrimaria` e `segurando` utilizados no código.

Comment: Espero não ter complicado demais o entendimento. Editei mais uma vez

Answer (score 0):

O problema aí deve estar em como você cria essa estrutura de dados que você chama de "matriz" -

Na verdade, você tem uma lista de listas  - que poderia ser usada do jeito que o trecho de código que você apresenta quer fazer sem problemas.

Mas em Python não existem matrizes multidimensionais nativas - e há formas certas e formas erradas de se criar "listas de listas". Se você cria da forma errada, vai acontecer que uma referência para a mesma lista "coluna" - ou seja, se você insere um elemento na posição `[0][0]` e sua coluna `[0]` é o mesmo objeto que está em outras posições, vai ver o número colocado ali também:

```
In [1]: a = [0,0,0,0]                                                                                                                                  

In [2]: b = [a, a,a,a]                                                                                                                                 

In [3]: b                                                                                                                                              
Out[3]: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

In [4]: b[0][0] = 23                                                                                                                                   

In [5]: b                                                                                                                                              
Out[5]: [[23, 0, 0, 0], [23, 0, 0, 0], [23, 0, 0, 0], [23, 0, 0, 0]]
```

O ideal é ou usar numpy, que tem de fato objetos de array multidimensionais, ou criar uma classe bem pensada para guardar seus dados, implementando os métodos `__getitem__` e `__setitem__` para tratar referências a linha e coluna de uma vez.

```
In [6]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                             

In [7]: c = np.zeros((4, 4))                                                                                                                           

In [8]: c                                                                                                                                              
Out[8]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])

In [9]: c[0,0] = 23                                                                                                                                    

In [10]: c                                                                                                                                             
Out[10]: 
array([[23.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

(e não, seu exemplo "mínimo completo e verificável" está bem longe de ser isso - não só não incli a criação da sua matriz, como nem é Python válido -  identação não é "brinquedo" em Python - você começa o primeiro `for` numa coluna arbitrária  - isso é um erro de sintaxe. Na linha 3 você testa uma variável que não apareceu antes na sua listagem, como isso é um "exemplo completo"???.

Dica: idente sempre usando 4 espaços, não tentando alinhar seu código com uma posição qualquer na linha de cima)